# How to publish a specific file instead of publishing the entire SQL Server database project

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, publishing

In my current application for versioning and deployment of my SQL Server database, I am using a SQL Server database project.

1. The target database for the project is our development database
2. We are using Management Studio for updating database and using "Schema Comparison" and then "Update" for updating the SQL Server database project
3. End of the day the web application project and SQL Server database project are published

   - Web application project published to Azure app service.
   - SQL Server database project published to Azure database.

My question is while I am publishing the database project I had to publish the entire project each and every time while may be the change is in a single stored procedure file.

How to publish a single file instead of publishing the entire SQL Server database project ?

Comment: The entire project is needed in order to compare the source and target schemas and figure out which change needs to be applied -- that's precisely what "schema comparison" does. If you want to be clever about it and go "no, I happen to know exactly what's changed already" nothing's stopping you from doing the `ALTER PROCEDURE` yourself. You cannot "publish" the procedure on its own, however, as the resulting model would simply be incorrect, lacking all the objects the procedure is referencing.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert for the reply. I am using the entire project for schema comparison. This is not the issue. The problem is as we are using EF code first approach we don't want to publish the table schema.

Comment: You may want to tag your question with `entity-framework` (and ditch the useless `publishing` tag) and make that scenario more clear in your question itself. I don't use EF and I couldn't tell you what a sensible workflow is in that case. There is some overlap between what EF does and what database projects do in that case. It is possible to exclude objects in a DACPAC from publication/comparison; see [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ssdt/new-advanced-publish-options-to-specify-object-types-to-exclude-or-not-drop/). You can also do some of that programmatically.

Comment: I am not sure why someone is recommending tagging with EF as there is no evidence to suggest that is part of this scenario. If you use a devops pipeline to release the changes, a DAQPAC would be used (which essentially is the changes). I think we need more information about your process in order to give a good recommendation.

Comment: Thanks @DrDoomPDX. I read about the DAQPAC file but unfortunately we are not using devops pipe line. We are just publishing database project by clicking Publish and setting the target database connection. Is it the right way of doing this ?

Comment: It is not the way I would want to do that. Any time you manually do something, you introduce a greater margin of error. If you use a CD pipeline, and get through the initial bumps in the process, you will have a predictable and reliable process.